# How to Extend Timeout of Hangfire Job?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am new to Hangfire.  I am using Hangfire 1.7.6 with SQL Server back end, and entity framework.  I have a requirement to set up a Hangfire job for 1 time use that can be manually triggered from the Hangfire dashboard.  I set up a Recurring job with a start cron expression of "0 0 31 2 0" to prevent the recurring job from recurring and make it manually triggered.  The end user will then trigger the job at will for a 1 time run.  The job takes takes more than 30 minutes to execute.  If the end user keeps the Hangfire dashboard open, the job runs to completion (well over 30 minutes).  However, we cannot be certain that or VPN will allow the end user to be connected long enough for the job to finish.  If we do not keep the Hangfire dashboard open, the job stops after 30 minutes and we do not want to restart the job.

Our long running job takes several hours to run.

My understanding is that Hangfire is supposed to run the thread/job for 30 minutes and then put it on a new thread or job and resume.   In my case, it just stops at 30 minutes. I presume because I have the cron expression of "0 0 31 2 0."

I have set the sql server storage options

```
        var sqlOptions = new SqlServerStorageOptions
        {
            PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = false,
            //InvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(35),
            SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(35)
            
        };
        
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("AContext", sqlOptions);
        
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Datacleanup", () => Datacleanup(), "0 0 31 2 0", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Is there a way I can change the timeout to be more than 30 minutes?    I have tried setting the Invisibility Timeout and the Sliding Visibility timeout and neither has any effect.

Comment: We have the same trouble, even add a filter with the:
```public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)``` method where a JobExpirationTimeout set to hours, but no success.